# One to many mapping with list result illegal Argument exception not a known entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am new to JPA. Need to insert data to two databases tables(two tables are different that means no foreign key relationship).I am using POSTMAN to send json data from URL as well as payload body section.
Two entity classes are shown below.

**USERREDIRECT.JAVA**`

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.QueryHint;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getuserRedirectById", query = "SELECT a FROM userRedirect a WHERE a.redirectId=:redirectId", hints = @QueryHint(name = "eclipselink.refresh", value = "true"))
    ,
    @NamedQuery(name = "getAlluserRedirect", query = "SELECT a FROM userRedirect a order by a.redirectId", hints = @QueryHint(name = "eclipselink.refresh", value = "true"))})

@Table(name = "userRedirect")
public class userRedirect {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "redirect_id")
    @JsonProperty("redirect_id")
    private String redirectId;

    @Column(name = "loop_ind")
    @JsonProperty("loop_ind")
    private String loopInd;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRedirectEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<userRedirectRicTgrpDetails> userRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList;

    public userRedirect() {

    }

    public String getLoopInd() {
        return loopInd;
    }

    public void setLoopInd(String loopInd) {
        this.loopInd = loopInd;
    }

    public List<userRedirectRicTgrpDetails> getuserRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList() {
        return userRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList;
    }

    public void setuserRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList(List<userRedirectRicTgrpDetails> userRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList) {
        this.userRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList = userRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList;
    }

    /**
     * @return the redirectId
     */
    public String getRedirectId() {
        return redirectId;
    }

    /**
     * @param redirectId the redirectId to set
     */
    public void setRedirectId(String redirectId) {
        this.redirectId = redirectId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "userRedirect :: RedirectId: " + redirectId + ", LoopInd : "
                + loopInd + ", Ric_Tgrp Details : " + userRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList;
    }

}
```

**userRedirectRicTgrpDetails.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.QueryHint;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getuserRedirectDetailsById", query = "SELECT a FROM userRedirectRicTgrpDetails a WHERE a.userRedirectEntity.redirectId=:redirectId ORDER BY a.priority", hints = @QueryHint(name = "eclipselink.refresh", value = "true"))
    ,
@NamedQuery(name = "getAlluserRedirectDetails", query = "SELECT a FROM userRedirectRicTgrpDetails a ORDER BY a.priority", hints = @QueryHint(name = "eclipselink.refresh", value = "true"))})

@Table(name = "userRedirect_ric_tgrp_details")
public class userRedirectRicTgrpDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "row_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "redirect_id")
    private userRedirect userRedirectEntity;

    @Column(name = "ric")
    @JsonProperty("ric")
    private String ric;

    @Column(name = "tgrp")
    @JsonProperty("tgrp")
    private String tgrp;

    @Column(name = "priority")
    @JsonProperty("priority")
    private int priority;

    public userRedirectRicTgrpDetails() {

    }

    public userRedirect getuserRedirect() {
        return userRedirectEntity;
    }

    public void setuserRedirect(userRedirect userRedirect) {
        this.userRedirectEntity = userRedirect;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ric
     */
    public String getRic() {
        return ric;
    }

    /**
     * @param ric the ric to set
     */
    public void setRic(String ric) {
        this.ric = ric;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tgrp
     */
    public String getTgrp() {
        return tgrp;
    }

    /**
     * @param tgrp the tgrp to set
     */
    public void setTgrp(String tgrp) {
        this.tgrp = tgrp;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "userRedirectRicTgrpDetails ::RowId : " + id + ", RedirectId : " + userRedirectEntity.getRedirectId() + ", Ric : " + ric + ", Tgrp : " + tgrp
                + ", Priority : " + priority;
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
SEVERE: Unexpected error while creating new RedirectGroup  Exception =
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: callRedirect :: RedirectId: 1000, Lo
    opInd : ORIG, Ric_Tgrp Details : [callRedirectRicTgrpDetails ::RowId : 0, Redire
    ctId : 1000, Ric : RICXXX3, Tgrp : TGRPXXXX3, Priority : 1] is not a known entit
    y type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewO
    bjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4184)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(Entity
    ManagerImpl.java:368)
```

**Database schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userRedirect` (
`redirect_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`loop_ind` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`redirect_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userRedirect_ric_tgrp_details` (
`row_id` int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT,
`redirect_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`ric` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`tgrp` varchar (20) NOT NULL,
`priority` int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`)
);
```

**JSON INPUT:**

```
{
   "loop_ind": "ORIG",
   "callRedirectRicTgrpDetailsList": [{
        "ric": "RICXXX3",
        "tgrp": "TGRPXXXX3",
         "priority": 1
    }]
}
```

and redirect_id is given from URL

**Persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="TEST_CALLREDIRECT_PERSISTENCE"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<class>com.mypackage.userRedirect</class>
<class>com.mypackage.userRedirectRicTgrpDetails</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>      
<properties>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"      value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/CallRedirect" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"     value="root" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
</properties>   
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**DAO.Class:**

```
    public userRedirect createNewuserRedirect(userRedirect userRedirect){
    try {
        System.out.println("inside dao.....");
        LOGGER.fine("createNewRedirectGroup method invoked in dao with userRedirect : " + userRedirect);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(userRedirect);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return userRedirect;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please respect the Java naming conventions, and indent your code properly to make it readable. That said, have you registered those two entity classes into the persistence.xml file?

Comment: Please show your code when persist the entity

Comment: The error message talks about creating a RedirectGroup. What is that? The classes are named userRedirect and userRedirectRicTgrpDetails, but your persistence.xml only has CallRedirect and CallRedirectGroup. So no, you haven't registered these classes in the persistence.xml file.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i forget renamed in persistence.xml.Now i changed to userRedirect and userRedirectRicTgrpDetails in above question.

Comment: Still i got the same exception

Comment: Show the new exception then, as it isn't clear what object you are passing in to the persist call. You might try adding your own debugging code to see what is passed in exactly, and turn on EclipseLink logging to make sure that the persistence context that is picked up by the application is the one you think it is, and not something else you deployed earlier.  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging